# List all possible occurrences within a column?

Tags: r

I am trying to merge a data.frame and a column from another data.frame, but have so far been unsuccessful.

My first data.frame [Frequencies] consists of 2 columns, containing 47 upper/ lower case alpha characters and their frequency in a bigger data set. For example purposes:

```
Character<-c("A","a","B","b")
Frequency<-(100,230,500,420)
```

The second data.frame [Sequences] is 93,000 rows in length and contains 2 columns, with the 47 same upper/ lower case alpha characters and a corresponding qualitative description. For example:

```
Character<-c("a","a","b","A")
Descriptor<-c("Fast","Fast","Slow","Stop")
```

I wish to add the descriptor column to the [Frequencies] data.frame, but not the 93,000 rows! Rather, what each "Character" represents. For example:

```
Character<-c("a")
Frequency<-c("230")
Descriptor<-c("Fast")
```

Comment: You probably want to create an attribute of the data.frame (`?attr`) or convert your data to a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following can also be done:

```
> merge(adf, bdf[!duplicated(bdf$Character),])
  Character Frequency Descriptor
1         a       230       Fast
2         A       100       Fast
3         b       420       Stop
4         B       500       Slow
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
df1$Descriptor <- df2$Descriptor[ match(df1$Character, df2$Character) ]
```